# Downloading code from Google Code without using a version control system

Tags: google-code

Is there a method to download a folder from Google Code without having to use the version control system?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From what platform?

From Linux, if the code repository is subversion, you can do something like:

```
wget -m http://fofix.googlecode.com/svn/MFH-Mod/trunk/
```

There is a not so small caveat to that command, it will download the entire repository to the drive (that is all the tags and branches plus the trunk).

Another approach is using lftp:

```
lftp http://fofix.googlecode.com/svn/MFH-Mod/trunk/
lftp fofix.googlecode.com:/svn/MFH-Mod/trunk>
lftp fofix.googlecode.com:/svn/MFH-Mod/trunk>mirror <directory to download>
```

And that will download only that directory, recursively.

From Windows there are some mirroring apps, I can't recommend a specific one though.

Comment: Can you please tell me one mirroring app as I'm on windows 7?

Comment: There's a wget tool you can download for Windows.

Answer (score 9):

I was looking for the same thing. The next best approach could be to use the following minimalistic standalone executable for Windows (~8.45 KB only):
http://downloadsvn.codeplex.com/

It's far better than having to install a standard SVN or GIT version-control system (you should have .NET Framework installed though). Although this is an old post, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

I know that this is a pretty old post, but for people which get here by googling, I want to say, that you can download the clean trunk instead of the entire repository with wget using this address:

```
[project_name_here].googlecode.com/svn/trunk
```

Instead of:

```
code.google.com/p/[project_name_here]/source/browse/trunk
```

Answer (score 2):

Many of the projects have a "Downloads" tab where they will offer the source code in a zip file. This might be the easiest way to access a specific version of the code. As for accessing the live repository you might be out of luck.

Comment: Depending on the scm used in the googlecode project it is incorrect to say that.