# Editing Google Code source from web?

Tags: google-code, svn

I'm using an iPad and would really like to work on a LaTeX document that I have in a google code project. Are there any apps that allow you to edit a document off an SVN server?

Related question: [Downloading code from Google Code without using a version control system](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/570/downloading-code-from-google-code-without-using-a-version-control-system)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using an iPad, there should be an app for that. I found [iVersion](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/iversion/id320298553?mt=8):

> With iVersion you can vie and edit
>   your source code even when your away
>   from your desktop.

I haven't tried it my self but it looks promising.